# How to exchange 0 and ^ behaviour in vim

Tags: vim

I don't know why after this

```
" Exchange 0 and ^
noremap 0 ^
noremap ^ 0
```

they both have the same behaviour as `^`.

Same with

```
" Exchange $ and _
noremap $ _
noremap _ $
```

`$` goes to the new line character before having this. But after that both `$` and `_` go to the last character and I don't have a way to go the new line character.

How do I make `^` go to the beginning of the line including whitespace and `0` go to the first non-whitespace character in the line? Maybe this is fine and some plugin is changing it's behaviour. Does it work fine for you?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. After adding your mappings, what does `:verbose map ^` show you? How about `:verbose map 0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
noremap 0 g^
noremap ^ <Home>
```

You just have to make sure they do not depend on each other.